# Page keeps refreshing in mobile android & iOS browser while scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, html

I have made simple website [surajcreator.com/indermenschen](http://surajcreator.com/indermenschen) . But the problem is in mobile device while scrolling page automatically refreshes itself. It has some scripts for background image slide. I don't understand where the problem is. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried removing some scripts to see what causes the issue? You could also check which script uses an `onscroll` event and post that code.

Comment: You have conflicting versions of JQuery as well, make sure you're using `JQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: Well it has problem only with android browser. In windows ie it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Whoever stumbles upon this question could try to suppress the `touchstart` and `touchend` events, like

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    console.log('touchstart');

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

In my case it was a manual page refresh, triggered by the `window resize` event, as I wanted to calculate dimensions etc. Turns out the `resize` event might be triggered by appearing control bars on mobile devices.